# What is the new "and" keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, preview

I was just writing C# code and intellisense gave me a suggestion for the "and" keyword.

```
    if (context.Request.Parameters[0] is string operationType and )
```

In the above snippet the "and" in the end was suggested. Selecting it caused the following error to pop-up.

> Error CS8652 The feature 'and pattern' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*.

My main question is where I can find the documentation for this feature?

Comment: Those are introduced in the upcoming C# 9, so they're not in the docs yet. You can find the proposal [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1350)